# JEST Mock implementation from a builder

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

Im trying to test something and I cant lead to the solution

```js
const Config = require('client-config')
const cfgM = Config.CFGBuilder.builder().build();

class ConfigService {
  static get(key) {
    return cfgM.getProperty(key);
  }
}

module.exports = ConfigService;
```

This is what im trying to test. The `get` from my configManager.

```js
const Config = require('my-config');

const { expect } = chai;
const ConfigService = require('../ConfigService');


jest.mock('my-config', () => ({
  CFGBuilder:
  {
    builder: () => ({
      build: () => ({
        getProperty: jest.fn(),
      }),
    }),
  },
}));

describe('testing config service', () => {
  describe('testing get', () => {
    it('should return db.name', () => {
      Config.CFGBuilder.builder().build().getProperty.mockImplementation(key => 'mykey');
      expect(ConfigService.get('key')).to.be('mykey');
    });
  });
});
```

The thing is im getting undefined from the `ConfigServivce.get('key')`

**Disclaimer: I didn't code the client-config module. It's just a module I must use**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't mock a return value or implementation for `cfgM.getProperty ()`, that's why you got `undefined`. For chain calls of methods, you can use `.mockReturnThis()` instead of return a nested object.

Here is unit test solution:

`index.js`:

```js
const Config = require('client-config');
const cfgM = Config.CFGBuilder.builder().build();

class ConfigService {
  static get(key) {
    return cfgM.getProperty(key);
  }
}

module.exports = ConfigService;
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
const Config = require('client-config');
const ConfigService = require('./');

jest.mock(
  'client-config',
  () => ({
    CFGBuilder: {
      builder: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
      build: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
      getProperty: jest.fn(),
    },
  }),
  { virtual: true },
);

describe('testing config service', () => {
  describe('testing get', () => {
    it('should return db.name', () => {
      Config.CFGBuilder.builder()
        .build()
        .getProperty.mockImplementation((key) => 'mykey');
      expect(ConfigService.get('key')).toBe('mykey');
    });
  });
});
```

unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/63198582/index.test.js (13.614s)
  testing config service
    testing get
      ✓ should return db.name (3ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        15.747s, estimated 18s
```